# Combine multiple CSV files on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerquery

The dataset I'm working with are saved as different files for each month, how to I join these files together in SQL Server. I tried using Excel and Power Query but the datasets are too large and wasn't able to load completely.

I tried to google how to do this online but all I got was just how to import CSV files to SQL Server.

Comment: So to check, you tagged this to powerquery but do not want a powerquery solution ?

Comment: what do you mean by join? write them together physically? or just union the data together in one long select? You should be able to do the second one by using the standard bulk insert

Comment: If there are many CSV files my recommendation is to load each of them into a temporary table structure - best as heap and nvarchar fields only. Best a staging database. Then load from this table using views for transformation and checking into final destination. Combining big CSV files into one file and then load this file into SQL Server is asking for trouble. If there is a logic in SSIS the load of multiple files can even be parallel executed thus time reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import each file into a separate table and create
a table for each month's data. You can use the Import/Export Wizard, BULK INSERT statement, or an SSIS package.

Once imported, you can use the join statement to combine the data as mentioned below :

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table_January
JOIN Table_February ON Table_January.ID = Table_February.ID
-- Add more JOIN clauses for additional months if needed
```

This will combine the rows from `Table_January` and `Table_February` based on the matching `ID` values.